# С каких пор в java появилась возможность импортировать методы?

Tags: java, импорт

Когда я начинала учить джаву, я читала, что форма использования оператора `import` должна быть следующей:

**import пакет1 [.пакет2].(имякласса|*);**

Т.е. импортироваться может либо весь пакет, либо класс, например:

```
import java.util.Date; 
import java.io.*;
```

А сегодня я впервые увидела такой импорт:

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isNotBlank;
```

С каких пор в `java` появилась возможность импортировать методы? Так было всегда, или это появилось в какой-то из последних версий?

Comment: с [1.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html), можно сказать, что всегда было.

Comment: @zRrr, спасибо за ссылку! Видимо, статический импорт я где-то пропустила)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такая конструкция называется статический импорт.
Появилась с 5 джавы, ниже можно почитать про нее:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html